# Merge Sort sentinel: What if your array contains Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: mergesort, pseudocode

I'm just getting my head round Merge Sort, and I was wondering whether the use of the sentinel value was considered good practice in the real world, or mostly an algorithmic conceit?

I get that it simplifies the comparison operations in pseudocode, where "infinity" is a valid value. With real-world arrays, though, the largest possible value for the sentinel is always a value that the array to be sorted could conceivably contain.

Comment: Where are you using a sentinel value in Merge Sort? It's not necessary in any implementation I've seen (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: Sentinels are more useful when there is a value which truly cannot occur. If this is not your case, don't use sentinels. Sentinels are anyhow a somewhat outdated technique, to a large extent replaced by iterators. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709709/is-there-any-reason-to-avoid-the-sentinel-pattern-in-java) on stackoverflow.